# Should one use TestCase or FunctionTestCase for testing in python?

Tags: python, python-unittest, testcase

While trying to get a hunch of TDD in python I encountered the `FunctionTestCase` class. I understand, that it defines equivalent functions to the `TestCase` classes.

```
assertEqual = failUnlessEqual(self, first, second, msg=None)
assertNotEqual = failIfEqual(self, first, second, msg=None)
# and so on...
```

Is there a significant difference in using `FunctionTestCase` or is it a question of flavour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FunctionTestCase` can be used for easily reusing existing code.  More often that not you will probably be using the `TestCase` class.

From [unittest documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#re-using-old-test-code):

> Some users will find that they have
>   existing test code that they would
>   like to run from unittest, without
>   converting every old test function to
>   a TestCase subclass.
>
> For this reason, unittest provides a
>   FunctionTestCase class. This subclass
>   of TestCase can be used to wrap an
>   existing test function. Set-up and
>   tear-down functions can also be
>   provided.